# IsPrime? - missing return statement

Tags: java

I'm getting a missing return statement (32) error when compiling and I'm not sure why. Any tips?

I thought the return status was my return statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeChecker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int number;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (isPrime(number))
        System.out.println("Your number is not prime.");
    else
        System.out.println("Your number is prime.");
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int number)
    {       

    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        boolean status;

        if (number % i == 0)
            status = true;
        else
            status = false;
        return status;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Think of what would happen if number is 0 for example.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a return statement after the loop:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number)
    {       

    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        boolean status;

        if (number % i == 0)
            status = true;
        else
            status = false;
        return status;
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Because the method must return a valueif your loop is never executed.

But your loop ever ended after first value, because you return in every case.

Answer (score 0):

Add a false return in the end. Because if your `number` is less than 2 for block is not going to work so you should have a return statement out of the for block

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number)
{       

for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
{
    boolean status;

    if (number % i == 0)
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;
    return status;
}
if(number==2){
   return true;
}
return false
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So if the return at the end is true, then say user inputs a 1, it will return as not prime?

Comment: it will shows 1 as not prime but it is going to show 2 also as not prime

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `return` statement at end of function.
You have added the return in `for loop`.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++){
        boolean status;

        if (number % i == 0)
            status = true;
        else
            status = false;
        return status;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this function is not prime number checker: algorithm would be finished after first iteration. This function will be prime number checker if and only if `i==number&&number%i==0`. Extract `status` variable from cycle and place its return at the end of function. Hold in mem: full number scan is not effective.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have already pointed out, the reason for the compile error is because it is possible for the execution of your code to reach the end of the function, where there is no return statement.

On a side note, I don't think the logic of the method is quite right. Shouldn't it look something like this?

```
public static boolean isPrime( int number )
{
    if ( number < 2 ) return false;

    for ( int i = 2; i < number; i++ )
    {
        if ( number % i == 0 ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```